# A phrase or single word for a person who always think he is important

Tags: word-request

Is there any interesting phrase or word used to describe a person who wants others to pay all their attention to him and think himself important than anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked synonyms for ***self-centered*** and found:

> *egotistical, self-absorbed, self-serving; narcissistic, inconsiderate*

plus the rather informal idiomatic phrase:

> *looking out for number one*.

which dictionaries define as:

> To act in one's own interests; to act in a manner advantageous primarily to oneself;  to do what you think is best for yourself and not care about other people.

Answer (score 1):

"[high-maintenance](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/high-maintenance)" - *informal (of a person or relationship) demanding a lot of attention.*

"[self-important](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/self-important)" - *having too high an opinion of oneself*

You can even combine them:

- My girlfriend is a self-important, high-maintenance girl. - *She is having a high opinion of herself and demands a lot of attention.*

Comment: Ohh! I’m upvoting for _high-maintenance_. That’s a good one, particularly in the context of romantic relationships.

Answer (score 0):

## Attention whore

'Attention whore' is a mildly derogatory term for someone who will act-out in order to garner unnecessary attention.  Being slang, it is more difficult to find authoritative citations; however, this is the best I've found.

From Wiktionary.com:

> 1: (derogatory, vulgar, idiomatic) An individual that routinely solicits attention through inappropriate tactics and provocation.